# Dice Game score and beginning doesn't work

Tags: python, dice

I recently started learning python and am trying to make a simple game in python 2.7 where a computer randomly generates a number between 1 and 6 while the player enters a number between 1 and 6. The rule is that the bigger number wins except if one person has 6 and the other has 1 in which case the person with the 1 wins. The game should also ask a first question and if the player answers "yes" then the game would continue. Else it would do other processes. When I run the code however, even if the number the computer generated is higher, it doesn't add any points to the computer. Also if I enter no or something else, the code proceeds to start the game even though I am trying to get the code to print some other lines.

I have tried just using if else statements without try and except as well as changing the beginning prompt to be a boolean statement.

```
import random as r

score1 = 0
score2 = 0

start = raw_input("Would you like to start a new game")


if start == "yes" or " yes":
    print "Choose a number between 1 and 6"
    print "Enter stop to end game"
    choice1 = raw_input("Pick a number")
    choice2 = r.randint (1,6)
    while choice1 != "stop":
        try:
            if choice1 > choice2:
                score1 = score1 + 1
                print "The computer picked: " + str(choice2)
                choice1 = raw_input("Pick a number")
                choice2 = r.randint(1, 6)
            elif choice2 > choice1:
                score2 = score2 + 1
                print "The computer picked: " + str(choice2)
                choice1 = raw_input("Pick a number")
                choice2 = r.randint(1, 6)
        except:
            if choice1 == 1 and choice2 == 6:
                score1 = score1 + 1
                print "The computer picked: " + str(choice2)
                choice1 = raw_input("Pick a number")
                choice2 = r.randint(1, 6)
        else:
            if choice1 == 6 and choice2 == 1:
                score2 = score2 + 1
                print "The computer picked: " + str(choice2)
                choice1 = raw_input("Pick a number")
                choice2 = r.randint(1, 6)

    print "Final score is: " + str(score1) + " and Computer is: " + str(score2)
elif start == "no" or " no":
    print "Maybe another time"
else:
    print "Please enter yes or no"
    start = raw_input("Would you like to start a new game")
```

Program output:

```
Would you like to start a new game no
Choose a number between 1 and 6
Enter stop to end game
Pick a number1
The computer picked: 2
Pick a number1
The computer picked: 4
Pick a number1
The computer picked: 5
Pick a number1
The computer picked: 3
Pick a numbersotp
The computer picked: 2
Pick a numberstop
Final score is: 5 and Computer is: 0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: ```choice1 = raw_input("Pick a number")``` this is returning a string. Use ```choice1 = int(raw_input("Pick a number"))```

Comment: also, `start == "no" or " no"` in Python is evaluated as `(start == "no") or (" no")`, which is always `True` since `bool(" no") is True`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, this statement

```
if start == "yes" or " yes":
```

Is evaluated as (start == 'yes') or ('yes').  Since ' yes' is a constant and always true, it will always evaluate as true.  Instead try this, it will take spaces off the front or back before evaluating.

```
if start.strip() == 'yes':
```

I would also look at the other places where you if then with multiple conditions.  Consider using parens to ensure the code is evaluating as you expect.  For instance,

```
if (choice1 == 1) and (choice2 == 6):
```

Also, `try\expect` is intended for exception logging.  I'm not sure what exceptions you expect to log here.  Probably better to check the user input and make sure it's a number explicitly rather than relying on `try\expect`